# How to get consistent error messages in localized OSes using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception, localized

I am running the following code on an italian OS:

```
Rename-Computer -NewName 'NewCompName' -ErrorAction Stop -DomainCredential ($dcreds)
```

In several different cases I see these error messages:

1. Impossibile rinominare il computer 'OldCompName' in 'NewCompName' a causa dell'eccezione seguente: L'account di riferimento è momentaneamente bloccato e non è consentito l'accesso.
2. Rename-Computer : Impossibile rinominare il computer 'OldCompName' in 'NewCompName' a causa dell'eccezione seguente: Nome utente o password non corretta.
3. Impossibile rinominare il computer 'OldCompName' in 'NewCompName' a causa dell'eccezione seguente: Account già esistente.
4. Rename-Computer : Impossibile rinominare il computer 'OldCompName' in 'NewCompName' a causa dell'eccezione seguente: Accesso negato.
5. Rename-Computer : Il computer 'OldCompName' con il nuovo nome 'NewCompName' verrà ignorato perché il nuovo nome è uguale a quello corrente.

If I prepend `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US';` to the command above, I get the following errors (all of them are partially translated as you can see except the last one):

1. Rename-Computer : Fail to rename computer 'OldCompName' to 'NewCompName' due to the following exception: L'account di riferimento è momentaneamente bloccato e non è consentito l'accesso.
2. Rename-Computer : Fail to rename computer 'OldCompName' to 'NewCompName' due to the following exception: Nome utente o password non corretta.
3. Rename-Computer : Fail to rename computer 'OldCompName' to 'NewCompName' due to the following exception: Account già esistente.
4. Rename-Computer : Fail to rename computer 'OldCompName' to 'NewCompName' due to the following exception: Accesso negato.
5. Rename-Computer : Skip computer 'OldCompName' with new name 'NewCompName' because the new name is the same as the current name.

Now my issue is that I am writing a script for which I need to handle different errors with different actions. My company has offices all around the World and we are dealing with OSes in more than a dozen different languages. The type of error matching I am doing is of this kind:

```
If ($_.Exception.Message -match 'The account already exists\.$') {...}
```

This is because all exceptions are of the kind [System.InvalidOperationException] (when catching typed exceptions) and even dissecting the exception I cannot find any reference to a numeric error code or else I can use through languages that is consistent and non-culture-specific.

Quite honestly I understand there are limitations when using MSDOS commands but in PS/.Net I expected that the developers have considered those challenges and given a way to work around them. I realize that the 2 different part of the errors come from different layers so the last part is likely surfacing from a stacked down call or something but it is in fact the second part that I care to address specifically all the various cases.

Any thoughts on how to deal with those various errors with different sections of code for each?

I have tried using [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US' and also set LANG=en_US.UTF-8 none did the trick.

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/wrong-language-on-errors/db09bf66-578f-4c41-b945-a9424d4b5560

Answer (score 0):

- The fact that you're getting localized *PowerShell* error messages implies that you're using *Windows PowerShell* rather than [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), given that the latter has never been localized.
- The parts of the error messages that remain in Italian - despite switching the UI culture to `en-US` (US English) with `[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'` - presumably came from the exception messages associated with *.NET Framework APIs*, which PowerShell only surfaces.

  - However, while built-in *.NET Framework* APIs respect an *in-process* UI-culture change too (unlike built-in *.NET (Core)* APIs, which seemingly aren't localized), this does not seem to extend to *system* error messages, i.e. those associated with the error codes returned from *WinAPI* functions - they remain in the language that is *persistently* configured for the current user.
  - In other words: You'd have to make `en-US` the current user's default UI language in order to see your error messages *fully* in English, e.g. with
    [`Set-WinUILanguageOverride`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride?view=windowsserver2022-ps) `en-US`, but that is presumably *undesired* - and would also require *logging off* and back on for the change to take effect.
- However, you may be able to ***bypass* the issue in favor of a more robust solution that doesn't rely on matching the text of error/exception messages**:

  - **Inspect the `.FullyQualifiedErrorId` property** of the [`[ErrorRecord]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord) instances that PowerShell emits (which may or may not wrap .NET exceptions).
  - Its value is *culture-invariant*, and usually provides a specific clue to the nature of the error - though I don't know if it is specific enough in *all* cases of interest to you.

Here's a simple example, which uses the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-errorvariable) to capture (non-terminating) errors in a self-chosen variable for later inspection:

```
try {
  # Provoke an error by trying to rename to the current name.
  Rename-Computer $env:COMPUTERNAME -ErrorVariable err
} catch {
  # Turn statement-terminating errors into script-terminating (fatal) ones.
  throw
}

# Note: If no errors occurred, the body of this statement will not be entered.
switch -Regex (@($err.FullyQualifiedErrorId)) {
  '^NewNameIsOldName' { "New name is the same as the old one."  } # take specific action here
  # ... place other, error-specific branches here.
  Default { "FullyQualifiedErrorId: $_" } # print the error ID
}
```

In the example above, which uses a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement to evaluate the resulting errors, [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `'^NewNameIsOldName'` prefix-matches the full value of `.FullyQualifiedErrorId`, `'NewNameIsOldName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameComputerCommand'` (of course, you're free to match by the full value too).